# Why does the getter function gives error when used in place of "?"

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I tried to give the values of column in SQL query using the get() function but it gives an SQLSyntaxErrorException.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("DB URL");

    String sl = "INSERT INTO users(username,password)" + "VALUES(" + beans.getUsername() + "," + beans.getPassword() + ")";

    PreparedStatement pts = connect.prepareStatement(sl);

    pts.executeUpdate();

}
```

Comment: Space missing before "VALUES"?

Comment: That missing space doesn't matter.  A space is not required between a `)` and a keyword, identifier, etc.  (Sure it makes the SQL more readable ... but the parser doesn't care.)

Comment: You really should **not** do this. Do not concatenate values into a query string. It makes your query vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use parameter placeholders.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Always include all available error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming<sup>1</sup> that those two columns are `VARCHAR` (or similar), the values need to be supplied as string literals in the SQL.  But your code for building the SQL is not putting the quotes around the strings.  Therefore, the SQL is not valid.

Another problem with creating SQL statements like that is that it potentially makes your application vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

`PreparedStatement` and `?` solve both of those problems.  The JDBC driver handles any quoting, escaping and other transformations needed to insert the values into the SQL safely.

---

<sup>1 - This assumption is based on the column names: `username` and `password`.</sup>